# PNG file fails to work when I deploy interactive knitr/markdown doc to shinyApps.io

Tags: r, shiny, r-markdown, rstudio, knitr

I [still](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43529332/4581200) can't get my interactive doc to incorporate a png file on shinyApps.io.

Scenario:

1. I have 2 files on my local machine: `.Rmd` file + `.PNG` file
2. The rmd file consists of the following code:

   ````
   ---
   title: "TroubleShoot"
   output:  html_document
   runtime: shiny
   ---

   ```{r ,echo=FALSE,eval=T}
   library(png)
   library(grid)
   img <- readPNG("./mypic.PNG")
   grid.raster(img)
   ```
   ````

   <sup>As you can see, I've tried using relative paths (i.e., "`./`") to make this code work. (I've also tried just using the image's name by itself).</sup>
3. However, the document fails to execute properly locally on my machine.

   - It generates the error: `Error: unable to open ./mypic.PNG`
   - Note: however, it does work if I explicitly define the absolute file path.
4. I try to publish the interactive doc to shinyApps.io anyway.

   - I use the **publish** button in RStudio's app window
   - I check the both boxes so that both the `.Rmd` and `.PNG` file are uploaded.
5. I *still* get the same error once the app is deployed: `Error: unable to open ./mypic.PNG`

**What am I doing wrong??** What can I do to make this work???

Comment: It does work fine for me on win7

Comment: Try add `print(getwd())` to make sure your working directory

Comment: I'm encountering the same issue. Did you ever resolve it?

Answer (score 1):

It works when using the right absolute path for shinyapps.io

it looks like this:

"/srv/connect/apps/APP_NAME/MyImage.png"

I used knitr::include_graphics("/srv/connect/apps/APP_NAME/MyImage.png")

I know it´s a post from 4 years ago, but I had the same question and could not find a good answer anywhere.